Kotlin LazyPagingItems and itemCount parameter init value to 0
I'm faced with what I consider a bug on LazyPagingItems for a few days and, now that I've found a workaround, I've been thinking about this and if there's an efficient method to solve the issue.
For those who don't know what I mean with the title, when collecting PagingData as LazyPagingItems, its parameter itemCount starts always with a value of 0.
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(innerPadding)
        .nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection)
        .fillMaxSize()
) {
    when (val state = homeScreenUiState.homeScreenMovieListState) {
        is HomeScreenMovieListState.Error -> {
            LoadingMovieDataImageDisplay(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.Center),
                image = R.drawable.movie_list_loading_error,
                message = state.message
            )
        }

        is HomeScreenMovieListState.Loading -> {
            LoadingMovieDataLoadingDisplay(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
            )
        }

        is HomeScreenMovieListState.Success -> {
            val movieList = state.movieList.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
            when {
                movieList.itemCount > 0 -> {
                    HomeMovieList(
                        movieList = movieList,
                        navigateToMovieDetails = navigateToMovieDetails,
                        lazyGridState = lazyGridState,
                        paddingValues = PaddingValues(
                            top = movieListPaddingValues.value,
                            start = 10.dp,
                            end = 10.dp,
                            bottom = 10.dp,
                        )
                    )
                }

                movieList.itemCount == 0 -> {
                    LoadingMovieDataImageDisplay(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .align(Alignment.Center),
                        image = R.drawable.movie_list_loading_error,
                        message = R.string.movie_list_connection_lost,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

If you, like me, utilized this parameter to display a message or the list itself, I'm sure you've noticed that it always displays the code where itemCount == 0 at the beginning. For this, now I've modified this part and added a LoadState check:
when {
    movieList.itemCount > 0 -> {
        HomeMovieList(
            movieList = movieList,
            navigateToMovieDetails = navigateToMovieDetails,
            lazyGridState = lazyGridState,
            paddingValues = PaddingValues(
                top = movieListPaddingValues.value,
                start = 10.dp,
                end = 10.dp,
                bottom = 10.dp
            ),
        )
    }

    movieList.itemCount == 0 && movieList.loadState.refresh != LoadState.Loading -> {
        LoadingMovieDataImageDisplay(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.Center),
            image = R.drawable.movie_list_loading_error,
            message = R.string.movie_list_connection_lost,
        )
    }
}

While I find this solution good enough for now, I want to ask if there is a better aproach to a solution.
Besides that, let's hope Google fix this in the next release.

That's not even a bug, because you are missing many case handlers from CombinedLoadStates
